# Why does Internet Explorer 6 for Windows Server 2003 not work the same as Internet Explorer 6 for Windows XP?

Tags: windows, ajax, internet-explorer-6, windows-server-2003

I am developing a simple webpage in [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003). I am testing the webpage with [multiple versions of Internet Explorer](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE): Internet Explorer 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8.

The problem is that only Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8 are displaying my webpages correctly. This started occurring since I used the recent version of jQuery.

When I try to test using Internet Explorer 6, Ajax controls do not work properly. The same page works in Windows XP on Internet Explorer 6 on a different machine.

I need to fix the bug I am having in Internet Explorer.

- Is there a bugfix so that I can test on Windows Server 2003?
- Is there some other method to test Internet Explorer 6 effectively in Windows Server 2003?
- Why would Internet Explorer 6 on Windows Server 2003 behave differently than Internet Explorer 6 on Windows XP?
- How can I make them act the same?

Comment: On last bullet. You don't make the IEs work like each other. You code in such a way that it will work on both. Also, Multiple IEs have know issues, which causes it to not behave like the indivual IEs. See http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE?page=2

Answer (score 4):

I've found when working with the Multiple IEs that they don't provide a perfect way of testing IE6. I'd recommend downloading Virtual PC 2007 and the IE6 image and seeing if your ajax controls work in that environment. You can download the IE6 virtual hard disk from

http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en

Comment: It really sucks but you are right (sad that Microsoft has to offer its own Image for one old piece of Software)... I'm actually glad that the big players are stopping to support IE 6.

Comment: Great daff i agree ur comment

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your last two bullet points is that IE6 is a crufty (buggy, insecure) old piece of software that does not implement the relevant W3C and ECMA standards properly.  IE7 is a bit better, and IE8 is better still, but the open source alternatives are superior in the area of standards compliance.

While there are a lot of people still using IE6, the proportion is falling steadily.  For example, the latest available Net Applications statistics show that IE6 is down to less than 17% and Firefox 3.0 is over 20%.

So what should this mean to you?  Well the aim of standards and standards compliance is that a web page that uses the standard in the right way should work, and look pretty much the same, on any standards compliant browser.  If you try to support a blatantly non-compliant browser you are going to have to incorporate all sorts of workarounds (alternative versions of pages, clever CSS hacks, conditional Javascript, etc) to get your pages to work across the range of browsers.  It is hard work.

So my advice is to not support IE6 and earlier unless you really have to.  Instead, spend your time making sure that your web page works on Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera.  My experience is that pages that work on one of the open source alternatives have a good chance of working on all of them.